# Boost .lib's for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

Where can  i get boost .lib for visual studio 2010??

I tried to rename the old .lib's for VS2008 but this didn't work for the threads library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Build the binary from source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source) if the distro supplied one is not compatible.

Comment: I think you link is off by one section. Better see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-simplified-build-from-source

Comment: @Vladimir Prus: No, I meant that particular section, that talks about bjam and friends.

Comment: Is there any reason why a section that gives two commands that are sufficient to build Boost, without reading anything at all, is not good? The section you linked is pretty advanced usage for the rare case where the straightforward procedure does not work.

Comment: @Vladimir Prus: This was a pretty direct question: I am assuming the OP knows about enough about Boost.